# Import emails ID from Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, etc. for "Tell a Friend" like feature in PHP

Tags: php, email, import, contacts

In a project I have to implement a way by which a user can import all contact information from the following:

- Gmail
- Yahoo Mail
- Hotmail
- Tweeter
- Rediff Mail
- Sify Mail

Are there any freeware scripts in PHP for this?

Are there any servers that may be providing such services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this source forge project (Contact Grabber) : http://sourceforge.net/projects/contactgrabber/

From the homepage.

> Fetch the contacts of the selected
>   site. Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail, AOL,
>   Lycos classes have been incorporated
>   as they are available under GPL.
>   Rediff, Orkut & MySpace classes have
>   been developed at Magnet. New classes
>   for LinkedIn & Lycos have been added.

Comment: @Shoban all functions are deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Contact Grabber project is not alive for quite some time now, I did find [Open Inviter](http://openinviter.com/) which seems like a very good replacement (didn't test it yet :))

Comment: Thanks for this info. But I have already used Contact Grabber in our project. But I will remember this product and use it next time.